# Ruby beginner needs a hand

Tags: ruby

I am a beginner in ruby. 
I've tried to run this code and it shows run time error. 
What's wrong with this code?

```
class Calc
  attr_accessor :val1, :val2
  def initialize (val1,val2)
    @val1=val1
    @val2=val2
  end
end
a=Calc.new(2,3)
a.add_two_numbers(3)

def add_two_numbers(v3)
  return @val1+@val2+v3
end
```

Comment: you should put your method inside class body

Comment: By the way, in Ruby it is not necessary to use return keyword. Ruby returns last calculated value by default.

Comment: `add_two_numbers` - why "two"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `add_two_numbers` is not defined on the class `Calc`, however you are using it as if it is. This is the problem.

I would presume you got a `NoMethodError`.

**Update**: As pointed out in the comments, in actuallity, the method is defined on the `Object` class by default, which then gets auto inherited into all classes, but as private. This actually means that you will be getting the error saying that a private method is being called. The fix remains the same, since the overarching problem is a confusion in how to define classes and their methods.

The fix would be to define the method on the class, by putting it in the class body.

```
class Calc
  attr_accessor :val1, :val2
  def initialize (val1,val2)
    @val1=val1
    @val2=val2
  end

  def add_two_numbers(v3)
    return @val1+@val2+v3
  end
end
```

Comment: Methods defined at the top-level become private instance methods of `Object`. So, the method actually *is* defined for `Calc` via inheriting it from its superclass `Object`, but it is private, ergo cannot be called with an explicit receiver. Your solution is correct, but the explanation is incomplete.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you are right I was not aware of this rule and had not adequately considered it

Answer (score 0):

So you are defining a method outside of a class (which is want we don't want)

```
def add_two_numbers(v3)
 return @val1+@val2+v3
end
```

You always want to make sure that you keep your classes and you logic as two separate entities in terms of organization. By that I mean:

Your classes in one file (calc.rb):

```
 **class Calc
      attr_accessor :val1, :val2
      def initialize (val1,val2)
        @val1=val1
        @val2=val2
     end
      def add_two_numbers(v3)
        return @val1+@val2+v3
      end
   end**
```

And your logic to access calc.rb in another file. Use require relative to access the logic inside the class file:

```
require_relative"/calc.rb"
a=Calc.new(2,3)
a.add_two_numbers(3)
```

*Tip: When I was learning ruby the best way to keep them in two separate files for better organization.That way you know you don't have a method somewhere outside of the class. This would avoid your "no method error"*